# Xbindkeys not working

Tags: logitech-mouse, kde-plasma-5, debian-stretch, xbindkeys

I'd like to map some buttons of my mouse, but it's not working.

I've been trying xbindkeys unsuccessfully.
Here is one of the commands :

```
# Bind "back" mouse button to Ctrl+F8
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key F8' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:6
```

If I type `xbindkeys -k` a white window appears.  I don't have anything in the terminal when I use my mouse inside and when I close it I have :

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 17 requests (12 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

but `xev` works.

I'm using Debian Stretch with KDE Plasma, I've setup xbindkeys to start on login and I run the command `killall xbindkeys && xbindkeys`
once the modification of .xbindkeysrc is done.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. With `xbindkeys -k` I get not results for any mouse button. With `xev` it works perfect. Did you solve it? How?

Comment: I don't get mouse actions too on `xbindkeys -k`, but they are working nevertheless.
For example, this configuration works: `# thumb wheel down => lower volume
"xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume"
   b:7`